# Is there a way to require a minor version be present in the URL path segment?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnet-api-versioning

I'm using the `aspnet-api-versioning` library to create a fairly simple versioning strategy, using namespaces/folders to specify the routes.  My startup code looks like this:

```
services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
    options.Conventions.Add(new VersionByNamespaceConvention());
});
```

My controllers generally look like this:

```
namespace Something.Api.V1_0.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public class MessageController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            var formattedVersion = GetApiVersionString(HttpContext.GetRequestedApiVersion());
            var message = $"V1: It is Get in v1 controller (version {formattedVersion}).";

            return Ok(message);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("specific-route")]
        public IActionResult SpecificRoute()
        {
            var formattedVersion = GetApiVersionString(HttpContext.GetRequestedApiVersion());
            var message = $"V1: It is specific route (version {formattedVersion}).";

            return Ok(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't focus on `GetApiVersionString()`, it's just a private method that formats the version string.

This setup allows me to send the following routes to this controller's "specific route" method:

- `/Message/specific-route` (this is for clients unaware of versioning)
- `/v1/Message/specific-route` (matches 1.0)
- `/v1.0/Message/specific-route`

Ideally, I would like to eliminate the second of those, and require that all calls which specify a version, specify a major *and* minor version.  In other words, I'd like the response to be the same to a call to "v1" as it would be to a call to any undefined version.  Does this library offer any technique to accomplish this?

Note: All of my namespaces/folders will follow the `V_x` format, so there will always be a minor version available in my scheme.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is - yes ... and no.

Yes, it is possible to force the formatted API version string value to contain the minor version. Using `version.ToString("VV")` will format the version in the `major.minor` format. If the minor version is unspecified, it will be assumed to be `0`. This is also true for comparisons, which means that `1 == 1.0`.

No, in the sense that a client *might* not specify the minor numeric version. While it may be useful in being 100% explicit, it tends to be more pragmatic to make it optional when versioning by URL for client requests. You are completely free to impose your will though and generate URLs that explicitly have the `.0` in it. Ultimately the net effect is the same.

You could also add some type of middleware or something, and short-circuit if there is an API version that yields `null` for the minor version.

> BTW: you can still use `HttpContext.GetRequestedApiVersion()`, but *Model Binding* makes this much easier now. You can achieve the same thing by adding an API version parameter. For example, `public IActionResult Get(ApiVersion version)`.